# How to add data to a column in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

This is an example of sheet (sheet 2) I have,

```
A      B  
       10  
       20  
       30  
       40  
       50
```

I am trying to hardcode a value, say "Data" to column A in my sheet 2 till the last row of column B so my output will look something like this

```
A      B  
Data   10  
Data   20  
Data   30  
Data   40  
Data   50
```

Currently I am using the below code but am getting an error! How to achieve at this.

```
Sub AddData()
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value="A"
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to add here?

Comment: I want to hard code the column A with any word till the last row in Column B

Comment: where is your lastrow Function ? is this your error ?

Comment: Apologies. Newbie to VB! not sure how to get the last row for a column in sheet2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub AddData()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value = "Data"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to have a value for LastRow. You can find the last row by using:-

```
Sub AddData()
   lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = "A"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another twist on the same answer ...

```
Sub AddData()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = "Data"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, -1) = "Data"
```

this will put "Data" string in any column "A" cell whose aside colum "B" one contains a number, as per your eexample

but you can vary this "filtering"

for instance:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, -1) = "Data"
```

will consider all cells in column "B" containing constants (be they numbers or text values)

while:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Offset(, -1) = "Data"
```

will consider all cells in column "B" containing formulas

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx